# How to sort a list of dictionary based on date as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to sort my list of dictionary by date -

here is my list -

```
data = [{'5-feb-2019': '34'}, {'21-jan-2019': '12'}, {'10-jan-2019': '34'}, {'5-jan-2019': '34'}, {'25-jan-2019': '34'}]
```

what i'hv tried

```
keys=list(k.keys()for k in data)
sorted(data, key=lambda d: [k in d for k in keys], reverse=True)
```

getting error 
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'`

expected result

```
[{'5-jan-2019': '34'}, {'10-jan-2019': '34'}, {'21-jan-2019': '12'}, {'25-jan-2019': '34'} , {'5-feb-2019': '34'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love using [`dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) to parse dates, as it is a no-brainer for the job:

```
import dateutil.parser

sorted(data, key=lambda _dict: dateutil.parser.parse(list(_dict.keys())[0]), reverse=True)
```

The problem you have is to sort with a dict_keys object, which is not sortable. You need to convert that back into a string and then parse it into dates so that you can correctly compare one date with another.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to date and use that as key to sort

Sort ascending order of Date

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(data, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(tuple(date)[0], '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

Sort descending order of Date

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(data, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(tuple(date)[0], '%d-%b-%Y'),reverse=True)
```